# Optimizing _metadata File Size in Dask with PyArrow for Large DataFrames

Tags: dask, parquet

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm currently working with very large DataFrames using dask and pyarrow for storage, specifically employing the dask.to_parquet function. My DataFrames are quite substantial, approximately 3 million rows by 2,000 columns, with timestamps serving as the index.

For data retrieval, I typically use slicing based on timestamps, like so: dd.loc[timestamp_start:timestamp_end]. Consequently, the metadata on the index is crucial for dask to efficiently determine which partitions to load.

My challenge arises with the growth of the _metadata file size as the number of partitions increases. Given that it stores statistics for the 2,000 columns, the file size becomes unwieldy, although I only need the statistics for the timestamps (index).

Question: Is there a way to customize the behavior of dask.to_parquet (with pyarrow as the engine) to only include index information in the _metadata file, and exclude the comprehensive statistics for the 2,000 columns?

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Fastparquet allows you to specify which columns to collect stats on, and also allows direct editing of the contents of metadata. If that is interesting, I can describe. However, much of each "column chunk"'s data will remain regardless.

Comment: The alternative is to have no/ignore _metadata, and have dask scan every file's metadata and either build the global metadata at runtime, or filter only on the workers. If you have many workers, this may be the fastest.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code snippet to generate the file you want to minimize